# Define a function that will be implemented by the user

Tags: javascript, function, language-design

I have the following example code

```
var object = {
    userDefinedFunction : function(){
        //no implementation, this will be defined by the user
    }
}
```

What i want to achieve is the user giving his own implementation of it:

```
object.userDefinedFunction = function(){
    alert("just testing");
}
```

I tested this and works as i expected, what i want to know is:

- is this the javascript way of solving this kind of problem?
- let's say that it's mandatory that `userDefinedFunction` is implemented, how do i make sure of this? I could rely on something like the following, checking for `implemented`, but i'm learning javascript so i want to know how to leverage the language:

  ```
  userDefinedFunction : function(){
      implemented = false;
  }
  ```

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this in javascript, but in java i'd make a interface or extend it, then just create the functions there

Comment: @Daniel: yes, my problem is how to properly do it in javascript ;)

Comment: I know, just suggesting ideas :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var object = {
    userDefinedFunction : undefined,
    anotoherDefinedFunc : undefined,

    /* ... */

    hasUserImplementedInterfaces : function() {
        if (typeof object.userDefinedFunction !== 'function') return false;
        if (typeof object.anotoherDefinedFunc !== 'function') return false;
        /*  ... */
        return true;
    }

};

console.log(object.hasUserImplementedInterfaces());
```

`hasUserImplementedInterfaces()` function checks for user function implementations so you can execute as first check using that object.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the way to go, but if your object has to be initialized somehow by the user, you can test in this function, whether `userDefinedFunction` is defined and throw an exception if not.

One idea that *feels* to be a cleaner implementation, is to let the user provide some kind of configuration object that defines the functions, something like:

```
yourObject.initialize({
    userDefinedFunction: function() {}
});
```

Comment: +1 I quite like that configuration object idea - definitely very extensible. It would depend on the application though.

Answer (score 2):

You could throw an error in the default implementation:

```
var object = {
    userDefinedFunction : function(){
        throw "userDefinedFunction must be implemented";
    }
}
```

or show an alert box, depending on your application.